# How to convert Observable<Object> to Single <Object> in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm new for RxJava and here I'm trying to return Single object of Object class by running some test cases in list using `flatMap`. I'm trying to return the `Single` Object from `Observable` as mentioned below:

```
private fun isTrusted(configs: List<Configurations>): Single<Configurations> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(configs)
        .flatMapSingle {
            val rate = it.rate?.profit
            val result = rate?.toMap()?.let { it1 -> tests.testRules(it1) }
            if (result == true.toString()) logd("---- rules: $result")
            res.toSingle()
        }
          .toList()
        .map { list ->

            list.forEach { it->
                if (list.contains(MATCH_UNKNOWN)) {
                    test.isRulesUnknown = true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Please help me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to map onto a `Configurations` somehow in that `map { list ->` lambda.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I’m trying

Comment: You haven't specified what Configurations is or what business logic is necessary to turn a list of things into it.

Comment: I need to return single object of Configuration, `if result == true.toString()`

Comment: What if none of the source configurations will yield true?

Comment: Else null nothing much. But I need to convert Observable to Single as I'm using Single type of object in Rx Chains

Comment: That's not possible. Nulls are not allowed and there is no such thing as an empty Single.

Comment: Empty Object would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `skipWhile` to filter out non-matching elements then use firstOrError to get the first matching configuration as Single:

```kotlin
Observable.fromIterable(configs)
.skipWhile {
    val rate = it.rate?.profit
    val result = rate?.toMap()?.let { it1 -> tests.testRules(it1) }
    val found = result == true.toString()
    if (found) {
        logd("---- rules: $result")
    }
    !found
}
.firstOrError()
```

If you can define an empty Configurations, the last operator can be switched to

```
.first(Configurations.EMPTY)
```